# Convert UTF8 to hexadecimal in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, hex

I try to convert a UTF8 to Hexadecimal in PHP.

the UTF8 is: �9(512�#

And in Hex this should be: 0xef 0xbf 0xbd 0x18 0x39 0x28 0x07 0x02 0x35 0x01 0x13 0x31 0x32 0x0e 0xef 0xbf 0xbd 0x23 0x08

Is there anyone who can help me?
Google didnt help me xD

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Try to convert" - how? And what is the result you're actually getting?

Comment: *"Is there anyone who can help me?"* [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1415724)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '�9(512�#';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
echo str_pad(dechex(ord($string[$i])), 4, '0x0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

However, it looks like your UTF8 encoding came from what is likely a byte array or binary that you turned into a string to see, and now you want it in hexadecimal.  As an analogy, this is like having a number in binary then converting that to base 10 then converting the base 10 to base 64, when you could convert the binary directly to base 64.  Skip the intermediate encoding and go straight to what you want.

I can only guess at how you got here and why you want to go there, but, if you're trying to get your data into a form that you can transfer by POST, or into some kind of pseudo-legible-looking string, trying going straight to base-64 with a URL encoding.

```
echo base64_encode($thedatathatgaveyou�9512�#);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! you sir, are a hero! I got this data from a sensor, and needed the value in hex to do further calculations